# Setting up DirectAccess on the windows server 2019

Tags: vpn, ip, windows-server-2019, direct-access

I have a couple of questions/issues setting up DirectAccess in windows server 2019.

I am new to this setting up of direct access but I thought I might check in with the experts as I have tried quite a bit on this but with no success.

### Background on my current setup:

I have set up a windows server 2019 standard with ip: 192.168.1.100 and I want this to be the dns server too so IP is 192.168.1.100.
I only have one server so it is also my domain controller.

I have configured active directories and users and computers (no issues there).

I have 3 PCs and 2 laptops at home. For my family to use.
However, I am wanting to take the laptops away on travel etc, and so I can access my server from anywhere. Hence I though either VPN / DirectAccess is a good idea.

all the laptops / PCs are now added to the domain and no issues there either.

I have requested from my ISP to have a Public IP (201.114.X.X - Just an example).

I have set up group policy to the server can map different network drives to all the PCs / lapoptops on the domain to access all the data from the server. All the domain computers pick up the mapping of the drives fine too. so internally everything works. Now I want to be able to access the server externally.

This is where I am at.

### Question:

I have installed the role in the windows server for Routing (VPN/DirectAccess). How to get set up that public IP above (201.114.x.x) under the direct access with single network card (Behind the edge network). I keep getting the Public IP or ipv4 address is not valid. Why is this? I am new at this networking stuff so please help how to set up this DirectAccess Public IP issue, I cannot move past this screen.

Please assist. I am happy to give more information for any questions.

Thanks

Comment: One question per post please. Visit the Help section to learn more about how this site works and why. Use the edit button to fix this. Also, what research have you done regarding this?

Comment: Yes I have updated to one question now.